# When did Close->off topic->Other Stop Showing Close Message in Comments?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-to-close

What changed in the last few days so that the comment entered as the reason for closing no longer displays *Comments* for a **Close->Off Topic->Other**?

I just voted to close [Ubuntu 18.04 Dovecot/Postfix can login to thunderbird via ip as server name but can't with domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60612159/ubuntu-18-04-dovecot-postfix-can-login-to-thunderbird-via-ip-as-server-name-but?noredirect=1#comment107233583_60612159) on SO, and every time before, after the close dialog provides the pre-formatted text for you to complete in closing under **Other**, that message was displayed as a comment to inform the user of the reason.

When I close a question for **Other** in a question that should be on another StackExchange site, I try and be helpful and inform the user. Something similar to:

> Good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackExchange site.
>   I'm voting to close your question because your question is not
>   "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange
>   sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix &
>   Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

The `"I'm voting to close your question because "` being the pre-formatted text that is displayed when you click **Close->Off Topic->Other**.

Is this a bug or a change. And, if this is a change -- why provide the pre-formatted text that we are supposed to complete if it is never going to be shown to the user?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just testing if this is displayed.

Comment: Seems to work now (on Meta, at least?). I used the VTC -> OT -> Other and the message was shown. Also, retracted the close vote. Dunno about main SO, though - might be a bug there.

Comment: If you check that link above to the Ubuntu question, you should see my close vote with the full text directing the user to one of those 3 sites. It never would display despite my refreshing the page and coming back to it. It's still not shown even now.

Comment: That... does seem strange. I don't recall off the top of my head if we show the comment text in the post timeline alongside the vote record or not, so I can't tell for sure if we just didn't receive/record it or if something else is at play. We'll investigate tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it afterwards. There is no message but [one close vote](https://i.imgur.com/wIherzp.png). Yet, also no [counter to any specific close reason](https://i.imgur.com/olFXJXB.png).

Comment: I make a point of entering a helpful message, so I always check that it displayed to the user correctly. (I do this routinely -- daily or so) This close vote tonight was the first time it did not display to the user correctly. Had me confused so I added another comment for him with that same info.

Comment: Related, on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344867/comment-not-posted-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate

Comment: Probably related: [I'm not seeing the "Does this answer your question?" duplicate message at all when voting to close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394542)