# I'm not seeing the "Does this answer your question?" duplicate message at all when voting to close a question

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-questions

I voted to close [Filter array of objects by range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60621810/215552) as a duplicate of [Filter Array in Array by date between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48227286/215552). I expected to see the now-standard "Does this answer your question?" comment below the question, in addition to the close (1) link getting incremented.

I saw the latter, but did not see the former.

Earlier in the day I had voted to close [How to output the total sum of the values in a html table column with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60621272/215552) as a duplicate of [Sum column values in table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41756911/215552). I failed to see my comment, but did see [a comment by Mister Jojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621272/how-to-output-the-total-sum-of-the-values-in-a-html-table-column-with-jquery#comment107250007_60621272). It was not upvoted, even though it was a comment pointing to the same duplicate question as my vote.

Now, I happen to be fine with not having the comment added. I find the new wording invites conversation, which I don't think is a good use of comments, and I'm not interested in debating with the OP whether my choice of duplicate answers their question. If it does not, they are free to edit their question to show how it does not and I may retract my vote.

In any case, did something happen recently that is causing my comments not to be added?

I'm using Microsoft Edge Version 82.0.439.1 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 1903.

Comment: Probably related: [When did Close->off topic->Other Stop Showing Close Message in Comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394519)

Comment: I had the opposite happen to me earlier today. A question was closed and the auto-comment that was cast when I was the first to VtC as dupe was not deleted. Things are weird.

Comment: You did remember to refresh the page?

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes, good question. Refreshed the page. Opened the page in a new tab. Opened the page in a different browser even :).